# The different between factory, config_dg, and resources_db

Tags: uvm

I found it sometimes confuse.
I will appreciate if someone could clarify the different between factory, config_dg, and resources_db

Answer (score 0):

- UVM Factory is a standardized mechanism to create different objects. It has only one object in the entire simulation space. It has various methods to create different `uvm_component` or `uvm_object` instances and also to override it.
- `uvm_resource_db` is the parent class of `uvm_config_db`, which is used to set different values in the registry and then get it. `uvm_resource_db` has 2 lookup arguments for this set-get mechanism, whereas `uvm_config_db` has 3 lookup argument. Please go through https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/what-difference-between-uvmconfigdb-and-uvmresourcedb